# CodeIgniter - replacing category id in with name in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, url-routing

I'm working on a project using CodeIgniter where my category URL-s are:

> http://localhost/SabLiveNew/category/**4**

But I want the routes to look like

> http://localhost/SabLiveNew/category/**NameOfCategory**

Can anyone help me out, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't thinks so we have way to convert number to text in run time. But you can archive it way you requested.

Ex:

**URL**

```
http://localhost/SabLiveNew/category/NameOfCategory
```

**In Controller**

```
public function category($getCategory)
{
    // set 01
    echo "Category is : ".$getCategory;

    // Set 02
    if ($getCategory== 'xyz') {
        echo "this is xyz Category ";
    } else {
        echo "This is not xyz category ";
    }

    // Set 03
    switch ($getCategory) 
    {
        case 'xyz':
            $category = "this is xyz Category";
            break;

        case 'abc':
            $category = "this is abc Category";
            break;

        case 'pqr':
            $category = "this is pqr Category";
            break;

        default:
            $category = "is not any matched category";
            break;
    }
    echo  $category;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in first catch the last index of url

```
$record_num = end($this->uri->segment_array());
or
$last = $this->uri->total_segments();
$category = $this->uri->segment($last);
```

now get category name from database table, in controller

```
$this->model_name->get_category($category);
```

in model get_category function like below:

```
public function get_category($category){
$this->db->where('category_id',$category);
return $this->db->get('categories')->result_array();
}
```

in controller function where call this get category function get category name.

```
$category_info=$this->model_name->get_category($category);
$category_name=$category_info[0]['category_name'];
```

now create redirect url;

`$url=http://localhost/SabLiveNew/category/$category_name;`

I think http://localhost/SabLiveNew/ is your base url so try this

```
$url=base_url().'/category/'.$category_name;
```

finally redirect

```
redirect($url);
```

Thanks